# NSMutableData to int conversion bugged in iOS 6?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios6, nsmutabledata

I've this following code segment. The output for the integer variable comes as expected in iOS 5, but some irregular output is coming in iOS 6! Can anyone please explain what's happening?

```
int XmlMsgSubType;
[XmlMsgSubTypeData getBytes:&XmlMsgSubType length:1];
NSLog(@"XML subtype data: %@", XmlMsgSubTypeData);
NSLog(@"XML subtype: %d", XmlMsgSubType);
```

Output in iOS 5

```
XML subtype data: <06>
XML subtype: 6
```

Output in iOS 6

```
XML subtype data: <06>
XML subtype: 985605638
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason on ios 6 there is no data in the XmlMsgSubTypeData object, then XmlMsgSubType would be uninitialized and therefore the value returned would be undefined. I suspect the actually error is happening where you read the data into XmlMsgSubTypeData. Try calling [XmlMsgSubType length] to check it is not zero.

Comment: Thanks! initializing XmlMsgSubType did the trick! :) There was no error with reading data into XmlMsgSubTypeData. Just had to initalize the XmlMsgSubType integer variable to some value, say zero.